# Changing svg color but only one polygon at a time

Tags: jquery, svg

I'm trying to make only one polygon change color at a time. So far two or more polygons are changing color at the same time. Any help will be very much appreciated.

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/xamonix/6em7qxx3/9/

Script:

```
    setInterval(function() {
jQuery(".st0").each(function(i) {
    var colors = ['#b30000', '#990000', '#800000', '#660000'];
    (this).style.fill = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
});
```

}, 1000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, all of them get assigned a new color. But since you have only four colors, the rules of probability say that for 25% of the polygons the new one will be the same as the old.

If you want to select only one polygon, you should not select each of them.

```
var polygons = jQuery(".st0");
var colors = ['#b30000', '#990000', '#800000', '#660000'];

setInterval(function() {
    var el = polygons[Math.floor(Math.random() * polygons.length)];
    el.style.fill = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}, 1000);
```